# Use a js plugin that modifies Event in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using Event.js to capture swipes, https://github.com/mudcube/Event.js, and if I try to `declare var Event: any;` and then `Event.add(test, "swipe", function() {}, { snap: 45 });` it produces the following error:

```
Error   1   The property 'add' does not exist on value of type '{ prototype: Event; CAPTURING_PHASE: number; AT_TARGET: number; BUBBLING_PHASE: number; new(): Event; }'
```

If I try:

```
declare interface Event {
    add: any;
};
```

I get `Duplicate identifier 'add'`

Why does it not override the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is already an Event defined in TypeScript so you have a name collision.

Can you alias it in your JavaScript, for example...

```
var eventJS = Event;
```

Then you could refer to eventJS in your TypeScript and avoid the clash.

Otherwise, if you only need the second add function, declare its signature and it should act as an override as long as it doesn't accept the same arguments.

```
interface Event {
    add(name: string, eventType: string, callback: Function) : any;
};
```

Comment: Dosn't work, stil outputs `The property 'add' does not exist on value of type [...]`

Comment: Which one did you try? The declare interface or the alias?

Comment: Both, the alias didn't do anything, as `eventJS` continues to be TS's Event object. Declaring the interface with an `add()` method or with an `add: any` property still doesn't work, the later returning `Duplicate identifier 'add'`.

Comment: The `var eventJS = Event;` needs to go in your Event.js JavaScript code, not in the TypeScript code.

Comment: Yes, yes. What was I thinking... But that is the only way then? Aint there any way to fix that without having to modify the library?

Comment: I have tested extending the interface and it works - but the behaviour will be problematic as it will look like other properties and functions are available that really aren't. I have updated the interface extension in the answer.